# Unable to setup gmail in Google Workspace

Tags: google-workspace, google-admin-sdk, namecheap

I'm using `Namecheap` as the domain but having problems connecting it to `Google Workspace`.

It keeps giving me the same error message.
It says I need to delete some registrar forwarding.

[image]

Maybe in the past I've deleted some of my domain settings by accident trying to redirect namecheap to `Google Workspaces`. I've had this domain for about two weeks but can't get it to work.

Whenever I try to send emails to this domain, it doesn't work.
[image]
This is my domain setting with Namecheap.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have updated the records correctly, wait for about 48-72 hours and do not make any changes to the MX records, or any email records for that matter. You can refer to this [support article](https://support.google.com/googlecloud/answer/10960972?hl=en#zippy=%2Cset-up-google-workspace-mx-general-steps)